# Evaluating $ \lim_{x \to 0}{ \arctan( 2 {\Large[} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{\sin^2x} {\Large]} )} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Having 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}{ \arctan\left( 2 \left[ \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{\sin^2x}\right] \right)} = L $$

The interesting part however is $$ \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{\sin^2x} $$ and $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\cos(x) - 1)}{\sin^2x} = \left[\frac{0}{0}\right] = -1$. With l'hopital's rule it's easy to solve - I'm interested in other methods though<sup>1</sup>. Hints are welcome too.

---

**Attempt 1**

Considering $$ 1 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x $$ Plugging in:
 $$ \frac{\cos(x) - \sin^2x - \cos^2x}{\sin^2x} 
\longrightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} {\cot(x)\csc(x) - 1 - \cot^2x}$$
which doesn't go very far.

**Attempt 2**

Considering:

$$ -2 \leq \cos(x) - 1 \leq 0 \rightarrow \frac{-2}{\sin^2x} \leq \cos(x) - 1 \leq \frac{0}{\sin^2x}$$

But $$ \lim_{x\to0}{  \frac{-2}{\sin^2x} } \neq \lim_{x\to0}{ \frac{0}{\sin^2x}} $$

so the squeeze theorem cannot be applied. (**bonus question:** can it?)

<sup>Please avoid Taylor expansion.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${\cos x-1\over\sin^2x}={\cos x-1\over\sin^2x}\cdot{\cos x+1\over\cos x+1}={\cos^2x-1\over\sin^2x(\cos x+1)}={-\sin^2x\over\sin^2x(\cos x+1)}={-1\over\cos x+1}$$

Comment: Nice one. [padding]

Answer (score 2):

Hint :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x }{x^2}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\cos x-1}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}$$

Both $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ are basic limits.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos(x)-1=-2\sin^2(x/2)$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\sin^2(x)}&=-\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{\sin^2(x)}\\\\
&=-\frac12 \left(\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{(x/2)}\right)\,\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why not also note that $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$ in the denominator?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, of course.  And then this would resemble your nice way forward.  This particular way might be useful to those students who do know and recall that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \to 1$.  If you think this is either redundant or otherwise not useful, I'll delete it.

Comment: not at all (redundant or not useful)!  It's another nice take.  I rather like the fact that some routes lead to a trivial limit while others lead to a nontrivial but familiar limit.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you!  I'll leave it intact then.  Much appreciate your comments!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- $$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\sin^2(x)}=-\frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2}$$
- $$\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$$

So, we get:

$$\arctan\left(2\cdot\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\sin^2(x)}\right)=\arctan\left(-\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=-\arctan\left(\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @πr8 Yes I did I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\cos x-1}{\sin^2x}=-\dfrac1{1+\cos x}$$ for $\cos x-1\ne0$

and

$$\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x$$

Answer (score 0):

$(\cos x - 1) / \sin ^2x $

$= (\cos x- 1) / (1 - \cos^2x)$

$ = (\cos x - 1) / [(1 - \cos )(1 + \cos )]$

$ = - 1 / (\cos x + 1)$

Comment: After picking apart the poor formatting, this answer is wrong: You have a sign error in your final step. (Also, this is just a version of Barry Cipra's much older answer, without Mathjax)

Comment: @T.Bongers, my answer isn't that much older.  Also, setting aside the formatting and the conclusion (which remains wrong even after the sign error was corrected), I like this approach better -- it's one equal sign shorter.  My reaction on seeing it was, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: thanks guys, it isn't my finest hour, but it's not as if it's my job or anything - yeah I messed the sign up then noticed it, but left the wrong conclusion of course.  I'm sure we all realise that similar answers can appear when a person is trying to formulate an answer.  Bongers, did you think I made it wrong to make it look like I didn't copy it?   I don't have Mathjax, but I'll look into it.  Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: This looks much better.  If you put a "\" front of each "cos" and "sin" (and change each "cosx" to "cos x"), it'll look impeccable.

Comment: Also, prefer `\frac{num}{den}` for fractions. For some reason it wouldn't render so I didn't propose an edit myself.